# Creating worksheets based on unique values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set sorted date wise and I want to copy the data based on month, i.e, data of each month to be copied to a new worksheet and the name of sheet would be the name of month present. 
Data set:
http://bit.ly/1CoHV5j

I tried running the following code:

```
Sub x()
Dim rng As Range

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheets.Add().Name = "Temp"
    .Range("H2", .Range("H2").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    For Each rng In Sheets("Temp").UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(Sheets("Temp").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=rng
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = rng.Text
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy Sheets(rng).Range("A1")

    Next rng

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Temp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With

End Sub
```

But this error keeps coming up:

"You typed an invalid name for a sheet or chart. Make sure that:
The name that you type does not exceed 31 charaters
The name does not contain any of thefollowing characters: \ / ? * [ or ]
You do not leave the name blank

Kindly help and tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

the text in some of the cells may have reserved characters... can you try the below, replace the sheeets.add bit with cleaned up string

PS: You should also make sure the cell you are using as a name is not empty

Full Code should look like something below

```
Sub x()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SheeetName as string    
    With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheets.Add().Name = "Temp"
    .Range("H2", .Range("H2").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    For Each rng In Sheets("Temp").UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(Sheets("Temp").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=rng
        SheeetName = GetGoodSheetName(rng.Text)
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = SheeetName
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1")

    Next rng

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Temp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub

Function GetGoodSheetName(fromName As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[\<\>\*\\\/\?|]"
        GetGoodSheetName = .Replace(fromName, "_")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you be a bit more clear where to include this function? I am a bit confused what to remove and add and how the final code will look like.

Comment: please see Edit above

Comment: It is showing Subscript out of range error now on this line:                                           .AutoFilter.Range.Copy Sheets(rng).Range("A1"). However when I change rng to rng.text in this line, it says can't rename a sheet to same name as another sheet. I don't know where is it going wrong.

Comment: Please try updated code - you will need to change the sheet name every where you use it so it is consistent. Also are the cells you are using for sheet name non-blank?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot: http://bit.ly/1CoHV5j. My ultimate aim is to separate the data month wise in different sheets whose name would be same as the data of the month they would be containing. So, it is finding unique months from 'H' column and using them to rename the sheets

Comment: Hi Sir, I did not see your edit earlier. Anyway, I tried running it but it is showing subscript out of range error on: .AutoFilter.Range.Copy Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1").